# CSS flex-flow wrap with nested divs

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, two intermediate divs and several child divs. I would like to have the child divs wrapping. The reason I have the intermediate divs is to be able to set properties (e.g. hide groups of child divs) on groups of the child divs.

When I set the parent div as `flex-flow: wrap`, the two intermediate divs (instead of the child divs) wrap.

The following jsfiddle shows the issue: Increasing width of the items from 260px to 270px moves the entire second intermediate divs in the next row instead of just the 4th item.
https://jsfiddle.net/bjonen/x7h5atd3/95/

Is there any way to get wrapping of the children and at the same time a way to target the intermediate divs?

```html
<div class="flex-group">
  <div class="comps">
    <div class="item">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      abc
    </div>
  <div>
  <div class="comps">
    <div class="item">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      abc
    </div>
  <div>
<div>
```

```css
.flex-group {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: brown;
}

.comps {
    display: flex;
    background-color: purple;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: I think you have enough reputation points to know by now, that the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: Other than maybe “dissolving” those intermediate divs by applying `display: contents`, I don’t see how this could work. Can you be more specific as to what you actually need them for? You said hiding groups of children - but that alone surely could be achieved in a different way. Is there anything else you need this particular structure for?

Comment: I did not know about `display: contents` and it seems to work fine. 
These are groups of "controls" in a dashboard that are supposed to be hidden from the user depending on the state of the page. So it's really just about grouping the components for joint hiding.